# MongoDb nested Array retrieve

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am using mongodb 2.6
my schema

```
{
  list:[
     { Sno:1,
       sublist:[
             {
                subid:"1"
                dats:"result"
             },
             {
                subid:"2"
                dats:"result"
             }
             ]
     },
     { Sno:2,
       sublist:[
             {
                subid:"3"
                dats:"result"
             },
             {
                subid:"4"
                dats:"result"
             }
             ]
     }
    ]
}
```

db.test.find({"list.sublist.subid": 2});

i want to return only matched data like this

i don't know how to use mapreduce for this solution

```
{ 
  sublist:[
         {
            subid:"1"
            dats:"result"
          }
         ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a projection http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/
In your case try with `$elemMatch` (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#proj._S_elemMatch)

```
db.test.find( {},
             { sublist: { $elemMatch: { subid: "1" } } } )
```